# Kubernetes Default Loadbalancer for a service run locally?

Tags: kubernetes

currently I have 3 virtual machines (1 master kubernetes node and 2 slaves).

I want to create a service which encapsulates 3 replicas of my container.

I am curious if by default, in this local environment, when creating the service, kubernetes offers a load balancer by default, even though it was NOT specified in the service yaml file. Does it offer round robin by default ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your not on a supported cloud provider, your pretty much stuck with NodePort or ClusterIP for service types. A project I used when I was experimenting with a local kubernetes environment was [Metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/). Metallb allows you to use the LoadBalancer service type and expose your service outside of the cluster network when running kubernetes outside a hosted platform, i.e., local test cluster.

To use Metallb, you must provide a pool of ip addresses the you can use on your pod network.
First create a config map with your pod network ip range --

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.240-192.168.1.250
```

Then add that config map to your cluster.

```
kubectl apply -f metallb-config.yaml
```

Finally add the metallb controller to your cluster

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/metallb/v0.8.3/manifests/metallb.yaml
```

Now you should be able to expose your service.

```
kubectl expose deployment name-of-deployment --type=LoadBalancer --name=name-of-service
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not practically use LoadBalancer service in your local.LoadBalancer service creates a LoadBalancer provided by your cloud provider if you are running on public cloud. You can set L7 load balancing capabilities via your cloud provide offering. Load balancing in L4 layer will be controller by kube-proxy which is round robin by default.

If you are using cluster ip or NodePort then also you are getting the L4 load balancing offered by kube proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do that because locally there is no cloud controller available.
When you will be in cloud and you created service with LoadBalancer kubernetes controller will talk to cloud controller and it will create loadbalancer in cluster. But in this case there is no cloud-controller available to create loadbalancer.